Can you force IIS Windows Security (NTLM) to request full domain username and password - not Windows Hello?
Can you force IIS Windows Security (NTLM) to request full domain username and password - not Windows Hello?
Since the domain administrators have moved to Windows Hello for clients and switched from on-prem AD to Azure AD (their description of it), what used to work automatically with domain credentials being forwarded automatically no longer works -
Users must specifically open a site served by IIS with Windows Auth in private/incognito mode so they can get the logon prompt, say no to Windows Hello (pin, face, etc) and specifically enter their domain username and password in order for the site to be served successfully.
Is there a fix for this, in IIS or .NET Framework 4.8 code?

This isn't a clear question yet. What exactly have your domain administrators changed? If they have decided to migrate to Microsoft Entra, instead of on-premise AD, then you should completely dump NTLM/Kerberos and embrace Entra ID based authentication, and Microsoft has Microsoft.Identity.Web available for all .NET developers.

@Lex Li - you're right, I clarified the question - We have so many legacy apps that switching to Entra ID is a gargantuan task - it begs the question why IIS would continue to offer NTLM if they know it won't work with Windows Hello authentication methods.

My comment above still applies after your edits of the question.
Azure AD is now named Entra to align with other Microsoft security products. So, what you should do now is to revise your .NET Framework 4.8 web app to integrate with Entra ID and Microsoft Graph for authentication/authorization (anonoymous authentication on IIS).
Samples can be found from this page under ASP.NET section.
